# Drivers for my Epson WP 4530

Tags: drivers, printing

I am trying to install my Epson WP-4530 using the disks that came with the printer.  It will print gibberish so I think all I need is the correct drivers for the printer. Is there a website or someplace I can go to get the correct drivers and software?  I am new to Ubuntu.

thanks,

Derric

Answer (score 0):

According to openprinting.org, that printer will work perfectly with the epson-201113w  driver.

[Go here](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-201113w/) and download the .DEB file (an installation file for many Linux distributions, including Ubuntu)

Comment: thanks for the great information Nate.  I am a brand new user of Ubuntu and I want to get away from Microsoft. The link that you put in your answer returns to this same page, it doesnt go to another site.  I really want to learn all about Ubuntu and how to get drivers for my other hardware, and software.  Like I said all the items I have were for Windows and I want to use them on Ubuntu.  After I get my printer working Is there a site to go to for assistance in these matters or is going to this site and posting the best source for help?  Thanks, Derric

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Derric, and for posting that self-referential link. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: This site (askubuntu.com) is a great place to go for help, as is ubuntuforums.org